# Submitting form with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Apologies if this has been answered before (I couldn't find the answer when I searched the archives)

I've got a page protected by a password:

```
<?php

if($_POST['pw'] == 'pw')
{
    //Page content
} else
{
    //Display password form
}
?>
```

Within the page content, I've got another form, which I want to submit using jQuery, and have the following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

  var dataString = $('input#input1').val();  

  $(function() {  

  $('#submit').click(function()
  {  
    $.ajax({  
      type: 'POST',  
      url: 'p2.php',  
      data: dataString, 
      dataType: html,
      success: function(data2) {
        $('#testResult').html(data2);
      }  
    });  
    return false; 
  });
});

</script>

<form name='form1' id='form1' action=''>  
  <fieldset>  
    <label for='input1' id='input1_label'>Input 1</label>  
    <input type='text' name='input1' id='input1' size='30' />  

    <input type='submit' value='Update / reset' id='submit' class='buttons' />
   </fieldset>  
</form> 

<div id='#testResult'></div>;
```

However, clicking submit then sends the form to p1.php?input1=test (i.e., the data string is being sent to p1.php, not p2.php).  If I edit the code and remove `dataType:html` and the 2 references of `data2`, then this doesn't happen (infact, nothing happens, so I assume that jQuery is submitting the data to the form).  I've also changed the `type` to 'GET', incase the 2 POST requests on the same page were causing problems, but this didn't change the result.

What am I missing to get the information from p2.php (i.e. `data2`) and displaying it?!

**EDIT**

Thanks to a comment pointing out a typo, I've changed `dataType: html` to `dataType: 'html'` - this now doesn't cause the page to redirect to p1.php?input1=test, but once again, it doesn't do anything (when it should still be returning the value of `data2`)

**EDIT 2**

I've updated the code so `dataString` is now:

```
var dataString = $('input#input1').val();   
dataString = 'var1='+dataString;
```

but this hasn't made any difference

For clarification, my p2.php just contains the following:

```
<?php

  echo "<p>HELLO!</p>";

?>
```

**EDIT 3**

I made the changes to my code has suggested by Damien below; I get the alert of "works!" but still nothing seems to be returned from p2.php, and nothing is inserted into the `#testResult` div.

Comment: Surely it should be `dataType : 'html'`? You want to say that its value is the string `html` not the value of the variable named `html`.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited question to reflect this!

Comment: From your description of what happens, it sounds like the default form action is being fired, not the code you have bound to the click event of the button.

Comment: Is `$(function()` the same this as `$(document).ready(function()` ? If not, you are referring to #submit button before it is even created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {  
  $('#submit').click(function()
  {  
    var dataString = $('#form1').serialize();
    $.ajax({  
      type: 'POST',  
      url: 'p2.php',  
      data: dataString, 
      success: function(data2) {
        alert('works!');  // ADDED AFTER UPDATE
        $('#testResult').html(data2);
      },
      /* ADDED AFTER UPDATE */
      error:function(obj,status,error)
      {
         alert(error);
      }
    });  
    return false; 
  });
});
```

**Edit:**
In p2.php:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST['pw']);
?>
```

In p2.php you then need to output ( using echo, for example) what you want to be returned as 'data2' in your ajax success call.

**UPDATE:**

Since you're Ajax request fires succesfully, that means either your post is not passed correctly, or you're not outputting anything. I've re-looked at your code and I saw this:

```
<input type='text' name='input1' id='input1' size='30' />
```

that means you're fetching the **wrong** $_POST variable!

Do this:

1. Since you're sending a name="input1", in your p2.php try with:

   ```
   <?php
   if(isset($_POST['input1'])
   {
    echo $_POST['input1'];
   }
   else
   {
    echo 'No post variable!';
   }
   ```

   And in your jquery success:

   ```
   success: function(data2) {
          alert(data2);  
          $('#testResult').html(data2);
        },
   ```
2. That oughta work, if you follow it literally. In the remote possibility it won't work, forget AJAX, remove the javascript and do a normal post submitting with p2.php as an action of your form :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried both `.serialize()` and stringing the dataString together manually (see my edit to the question; as an aside the code I've got in p2.php doesn't actually use the dataString at this stage), but neither have made any difference

Comment: Quick revision of my answer, I placed an alert both for success and for errors (this shoudl be done better, I know). See if any of the two fires. Or better, look Firebug or Chrome's dev tool to see the http requests and any error

Comment: Have changed my code to your suggestion - I get the alert "works!" but the result from the server still doesn't appear!

Comment: @ChrisW I updated my answer. If you follow the code I posted (esp. point 1.), it has to work.

Comment: Sorted - all your suggestions worked once I fixed my annoying typo - I had `<div id='#testResult'></div>`...

Comment: lol, everyone missed that too! I'm sorry, I wish I could have spot it before :) Anyway, glad it's working now. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataString = $('input#input1').val();  

  $(function() {  

  $('#submit').click(function(evt)
  {  
   evt.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({  
      type: 'POST',  
      url: 'p2.php',  
      data: "someval="+dataString, 
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data2) {
        $('#testResult').html(data2);
      }  
    });  
    return false; 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to prevent the default action of the form.
Try this:

$('#submit').click(function(e)
  {

```
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({  
  type: 'POST',  
  url: 'p2.php',  
  data: dataString, 
  dataType: html,
  success: function(data2) {
    $('#testResult').html(data2);
  }  
});  
return false;
```

});
});

Comment: _return false_ does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

The data should be formatted like this:

```
variable1=value1&variable2=varlue2
```

I also think you can remove the dataType property.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited the question to reflect this (unfortunately, it didn't make any difference!); as an aside, p2.php doesn't use the data contained in dataString yet.